# FFTSharp don't contain FFTfreqPeriod

Tags: c#

I can't find the FFTfreqPeriod procedure in FFTSharp the development tool tells me that it doesn't exist
What can I use to replace it?

I wrote so taking an FFTSharp example

```
double [] paddedAudio = FftSharp.Pad.ZeroPad (AudioValues);
double [] fftMag = FftSharp.Transform.FFTpower (paddedAudio);
Array.Copy (fftMag, FftValues, fftMag.Length);

// find the frequency peak
int peakIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <fftMag.Length; i ++)
{
if (fftMag [i]> fftMag [peakIndex])
    peakIndex = i;

double fftPeriod = FftSharp.Transform.FFTfreqPeriod (SampleRate, fftMag.Length);
double peakFrequency = fftPeriod * peakIndex;
```

I have to find the frequency to which a person sings
Thank you
Mimmo

Comment: What version of FFTSharp are you using? Are you using NuGet/`<PackageReference>`?

Comment: Version 1.0.5.0 i don't find most recvent version. Can yoy tell me where is the last version